# Locate doesn't work

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, locate

System: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa, edition: Cinnamon

Got a problem with a `locate` command. I created `test.txt` file on a desktop. After that I did:

```
sudo updatedb
```

However

```
locate test.txt -i
```

still doesn't show anything.

Permissions to `mlocate.db`: `-rw-r----`
Working on normal user, not root (that's why I was using sudo command)

Comment: It is better to fix permissions that to use `sudo` (not an answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `updatedb` command will scan the filesystems on your system and create an index of the names of the available files and directories.  This indexing is performed as a non-privileged user.  This means that the index will only ever contain the names of files that are accessible by *all* the system's users.

Since your home directory is only accessible to yourself (you say in comments that you have `rwx------` permissions on it), this means that it *will not be indexed* by `updatedb`.  This in turn means that `locate` will never return names from within your home directory (using `sudo locate` instead of just `locate` will still query the same index, so that won't help).

To solve this, you have two options:

1. Loosen up the restrictions to your home directory (and to any directory beneath that that you want to be indexed by `updatedb`).  The permissions should probably read `rwxr-xr-x`, or 755 in octal.
2. Don't use `locate` to find files.  Instead use `find`:

   ```
   find "$HOME" -name test.txt
   ```

   This would look for anything called `test.txt` in or under your home directory.